# How can I add this preg_match to my PHP script?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a script for finding files with a higher revision (based on a file naming convention).

I.E **Ultimate Spreadsheet (Rev A).xls** gets removed if **Ultimate Spreadsheet (Rev B).xls** existed. It does the same with version numbers pretty well. I'm looking to add functionality for basically the same thing to happen - but to include files with no "Rev", as some filenames have no "Rev" at all.

So for example I wanted to add functionality for:

**Ultimate Powerpoint.ppt** to be removed if **Ultimate Powerpoint (Rev A).ppt** or **Ultimate Powerpoint (Rev B).ppt** existed. I think I almost have the code to do this already based on it working with the first rule mentioned above, but I didn't write it myself and am pretty naff with PHP so was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction. Many thanks! My current code:

```
$fileList = trim(shell_exec("ls -a -1"));
$fileArray = explode("\n", $fileList);

shell_exec('mkdir -p Removed');



// Do this magic for every file
foreach ($fileArray as $thisFile)
{
    if (!$thisFile) continue;
    // Probably already been removed
    if (!file_exists($thisFile)) continue;

    $niceName = trim(preg_replace('%[\(|\[].*%', '', $thisFile));
    preg_quote(pathinfo($thisGame, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), '/') . '$/', '', $thisFile);


// Check for reversions e.g. (Rev 2) or (Rev A)
    if (preg_match('%\(Rev (\d|[A-Za-z])\)%', $thisFile, $revNum))
    {
        if (is_numeric($revNum[1]))
        {
            $revNum = intval($revNum[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            $revNum = ord($revNum[1]);
        }
    }

    $otherVersions = trim(shell_exec("ls -1 \"{$niceName} (\"*\"(Rev \"* 2>/dev/null"));
    if ($otherVersions)
    {
        $otherVersionArray = explode("\n", $otherVersions);
        foreach ($otherVersionArray as $otherFile)
        {
            preg_match('%\(Rev (\d|[A-Za-z])\)%', $otherFile, $thisRev);
            if (is_numeric($thisRev[1]))
            {
                $thisRev = intval($thisRev[1]);
            }
            else
            {
                $thisRev = ord($thisRev[1]);
            }

            if (isset($revNum) && $revNum < $thisRev)
            {
                // Other version is newer, bin ours
                echo "{$thisFile} has an inferior version number/letter [{$revNum} VS. {$thisRev}] - Moved to Removed folder.\n";
                shell_exec("mv ".escapeshellarg($thisFile)." Removed/");
                continue 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be more comfortable if you used git for that?

Comment: Or simply decide based on the creation / modification time stamp?

Comment: It's a script for running on sets of files, so I need to figure out a way of doing it this way somehow! :)

Comment: Don't build a script on `ls` output.